# How to exclude the last character when printing in a for loop using end=" - "?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print "1 - 2 - 3", but instead I get "1 - 2 - 3 -" when I run, for example, a for loop with `range (4)`. I am currently using "`end=' - '`". What should I do to exclude this last "-"?

```
for i in range(4):
    print(i, end=' - ')
```

---

1 - 2 - 3 -

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `end`, use `sep`.

The function `print` can take multiple arguments to be printed. You can then rely on the `sep` argument to define a separator.

```
print(*range(4), sep =' - ') # 1 - 2 - 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str_separator.join(iterable)` function. In order to work it correctly, every element in the iterable collection must be a string.

For your question the answer is:

```
print_list = [ str(i) for i in range(1, 4) ]
print(" - ".join(print_list))
```

It will print 1 - 2 - 3 as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure of amount and type of values you are going to print you could save them to some list and print them with argument `sep` equal to spacing of your choice.

```
to_print = []

for i in range(4):
    to_print.append(i)

print(*to_print, sep=' - ') # --> '0 - 1 - 2 - 3'
```